# Eventbrite: Specific categories omitted from API

Tags: api, categories, eventbrite

Hoping someone can shed a little light on this.  According to the Eventbrite API documentation (http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/), only the following categories can be queried with the event_search method:

*conferences, conventions, entertainment, fundraisers, meetings, other, performances, reunions, sales, seminars, social, sports, tradeshows, travel, religion, fairs, food, music, recreation*

Categories such as *networking* and *business* seem to be available on the Eventbrite frontend (http://www.eventbrite.com/directory), but not through the API.

None of the API documentation that I've seen give any explanation as to why that is - does anybody have any insight before I contact Eventbrite support directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All of the Eventbrite front-end categories will match the the Eventbrite back-end categories that are available via the API.

We made the changes on the front-end for aesthetic/simplicity reasons, but they all match to the backend.

Having a mismatch between front-end and back-end categories is obviously not ideal, and it's only temporary. We're in the middle of re-doing our taxonomy and we'll soon have this reflected in a new version of our API.

To stay up-to-date on announcements, check out here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/eventbrite-api